Not redirecting to login page after session destruction
I have a session which is having all the designated parameters like origin, credentials etc which is required to authorize the user to dashboard. Server is hosted on 3000 port and the Frontend is on 5173. Also i have included the cors middleware to avoid all the cors errors
Problem:
So, whenever I try to destroy the session from the logout route the session gets destroyed and when I try to go to the dashboard through the dashboard route I am getting CORS error and when i am doing the same through postman to check the headers i find Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials headers missing from the header.
Error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/getuser' from
origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: The
value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must
not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is
'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the
XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Solutions i tried
set the headers in the response in /getuser route so that when the session along with the headers I get the headers back.
/checklogin

/logout

/getuser

Trying to access the route after the session is destroyed should redirect to http://localhost:5173/login

index.js
import express from "express";
import database from "./database.js";
import t_login from "./models/user.js";
import cors from "cors";
import session from "express-session";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";

const app = express();
database();

const session_para = {
  secret: "secret",
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: { secure: false },
  store: connectMongo.create({
    mongoUrl:
      "mongodb+srv://shashankthapa:kanchaa12@cluster0.kpqtzvc.mongodb.net/employee?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=Cluster0",
  }),
};

const cors_para = {
  origin: "http://localhost:5173",
  methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"],
  credentials: true,
};

app.use(session(session_para));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors(cors_para));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));


app.post("/checklogin", async (req, res) => {
  const { f_userName, f_Pwd } = req.body;
  const t_data = await t_login.find({ f_userName: f_userName, f_Pwd: f_Pwd });

  if (t_data.length != 0) {
    req.session.user = req.body;
    res.status(200).send({
      user: f_userName,
      msg: "Successfully logged in ",
    });
  } else res.status(403).send({ msg: "user not found" });
});


app.get("/getuser", async (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1800");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "content-type");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "PUT, POST, GET, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS"
  );
  if (req.session.user) {
    req.session.save((err) => {
      if (err) res.send(err);
      else res.send({ userdata: req.session.user });
    });
  } else res.redirect("http://localhost:5173/login");
});

app.get("/logout", (req, res) => {
  if (req.session.user) {
    req.session.destroy(function (err) {});
    res.redirect("http://localhost:5173/login");
  }
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Connected to the server : 3000");
});

dashboard.jsx
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Dashboard = () => {
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getData() {
      await axios
        .get("http://localhost:3000/getuser", { withCredentials: true })
        .then((res) => {
          // console.log(res.data);
          if (res.data.userdata) {
            const username = res.data.userdata.f_userName;
            setUserName(username);
          } else {
            setUserName("sample-name");
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log("Error is : " + err));
    }
    getData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      Hello, {userName}
      <div>This is the dashboard</div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;

login.jsx
import { FaRegEye as Eye } from "react-icons/fa6";
import { FaRegEyeSlash as NoEye } from "react-icons/fa";
import { useState } from "react";
// import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

import axios from "axios";

const Login = () => {
  // const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [icon, setIcon] = useState("eye");
  const [type, setType] = useState("notvisible");
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [pass, setPass] = useState("");
  const [id, setId] = useState(0);
  const [msg, setMsg] = useState("");

  const handleToggle = () => {
    if (type === "notvisible") {
      setIcon("eye");
      setType("visible");
    } else {
      setIcon("noeye");
      setType("notvisible");
    }
  };

  const login = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await axios
      .post(
        "http://localhost:3000/checklogin",
        {
          f_sno: id,
          f_userName: name,
          f_Pwd: pass,
        },
        { withCredentials: true }
      )
      .then((res) => {
        setId((id) => id + 1);
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        // navigate("/login")
        console.log("Error : " + err);
        setMsg("Invalid Login Details.");
      });
  };

  return (
    <div className="align-middle">
      <h2 className="text-blue-500 w-1/2 mx-auto text-center text-2xl">
        Login Page
      </h2>
      <p>{msg}</p>
      <div className="p-5 border-2 w-1/2 mx-auto">
        <form className="flex flex-col space-y-3">
          <input
            className=" h-10 border-2 placeholder p-2"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter username"
            onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
          />
          {/* {usermsg} */}
          <div className="flex items-center space-x-1">
            <input
              type={type == "visible" ? "text" : "password"}
              className="h-10 border-2 p-2 grow"
              placeholder="Enter password"
              onChange={(e) => setPass(e.target.value)}
            />
            <span className="" onClick={handleToggle}>
              {icon === "eye" ? <Eye /> : <NoEye />}
            </span>
          </div>
          <button className="bg-green-500 h-10" onClick={login}>
            Submit
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;


Hi, Is the issue still persisting ?
